# Formula for magnetic forces from neutrino magnetic moments

Tags: neutrinos, magnetic-moment

According to [this review](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0601113v1), the fact that neutrinos have mass imply that they also must have some magnetic moments that are around $4\times10^{-20} \mu_B$ in units of Bohr magnetons.

Assuming a polarized stream of neutrinos coming from stellar or cosmic sources, a magnetic gradient $\partial_z B$ along the direction of spin should result in a net (albeit very small) force on both the neutrinos and the magnets

Are such forces measurable within our technological horizon? what should be the leading term contributing to this force?

Comment: Why would stellar neutrinos be polarized?

Comment: "assuming" for the sake of pondering the question, but if they pass close to a magnetar, they might be

Comment: see https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1742-6596/718/6/062076/pdf